# How is a category's `tree_id` determined in BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I observe that all categories have a `tree_id` of `1` when getting categories using the BigCommerce API. I was expecting that each top level categories and their children will have a different `tree_id`. How exactly is this category attribute being determined by BigCommerce? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A store can have multiple, independent category trees which are useful when using multi-storefront. This allows you to have a distinct category navigation on different storefront websites.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/448cda022db6a-get-all-category-trees

By default, when using single-storefront, all categories are assigned to the first, default tree which exists when the store is created. It has an ID of 1.

Comment: Oh, so a category tree is actually the whole thing? I can't think of use cases for non multi-storefront stores at least so I think I don't have to worry about that. Also, I didn't actually notice that Category Trees resource below (I thought it was alphabetical ). Thanks!